# Import a CSV into Matlab in multiple parts

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I have a very large CSV file (870mb) that I'm trying to import into Matlab. Some of the data are numeric and some are text. I have 16GB of RAM and a SSD but the import wizard script is using 37GB and doesn't progress past 0% scanning file after a couple of hours.

Is there a way to break up the import wizard script to import the first 500,000 rows and save them to variables and empty dataArray then import the next 500,000 rows and append it to the variables, etc, until the file is complete? I'm surprised that Matlab doesn't do something like this natively.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Matlab has almost _too_ many ways to import CSV - `importdata`, `csvread`, `textscan`, `fscanf`,... right down to `fgetl`/`sscanf` if you need to do more complex parsing. In the absence of any further details of your data and your code, it's hard to say what's most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the memory-mapping approach I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655303/matlab-xlsread-cutting-off-file-after-row-1048576/10655798#10655798). If you know the format of your file, or can deduce it from the contents, I have found this to be the fastest way to read large CSV files into Matlab. It also helps reduce memory usage.