# Matlab csvread: 450k+ columns

Tags: matlab, csv

I am attempting to read a file with Matlab's `csvread`.  It has 10 rows and ~900,000 columns.  In the case of such a large number of columns, the function returns a vector, as opposed to a matrix of proper dimensions.

In order to test this, I truncated it to two sizes using `cut`, and when there are 457,000 columns we have the same behavior:

```
>> A = csvread( 'test.csv' );
>> size(A)                   
ans =

 4570000           1
```

But when cut down to 45,700 columns, we have the desired behavior:

```
>> A = csvread( 'test.csv' );
>> size(A)                   
ans =

      10       45700
```

Of course, Matlab is capable of handling matrices of the size 10x457,000, and I suppose I can use fscanf in a loop (I feel like this would be less inefficient?), but I was wondering if anyone had any insight.

EDIT: I suppose I could also just make the vector into a matrix of proper dimensions--but I still would like to understand this seemingly strange behavior of the matrix

Comment: Are all elements included in the vector? If so, can't you just use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) after `csvread`?

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655303/matlab-xlsread-cutting-off-file-after-row-1048576