# matlab - CSVIMPORT function not working for huge CSV?

Tags: matlab, csv, import, csv-import

So I'm using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport) CSVIMPORT function, and I'm trying to import a CSV file that looks like this:

```
    2014-6-06 08:03:19, 439105, 1053224, Front Entrance
    2014-6-06 09:43:21, 439105, 1696241, Main Exit
    2014-6-06 10:01:54, 1836139, 1593258, Back Archway
    2014-6-06 11:34:26, 845646, external, Exit 
    2014-6-06 04:45:13, 1464748, 439105, Side Exit
```

and so on for 948739 lines. Basically, columns 2 and 3 represent peoples' ID numbers, and it describes calls made from one person to another at an event(ex. 439105 calls 1053224). Whenever someone calls someone outside of the event, their ID shows up as "external".

I only need to import columns 2 and 3(Ex. 439105 & 1053224). The problem is that I can only get my code to work on a small csv file size and not a big one... and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655303/matlab-xlsread-cutting-off-file-after-row-1048576) question, a csv file with over a million lines worked.

According to the documentation:

> [C1 C2 C3] = CSVIMPORT( fileName, 'columns', {'C1', 'C2', C3'}, ... ) 
>       This form returns the data from columns in output variables C1, C2 and C3 respectively, the 
>       column names are case-sensitive and must match a column name in the file exactly. When fetching 
>       data in column mode the number of output columns must match the number of columns to read or it 
>       must be one. In the latter case the data from the columns is returned as a single cell matrix.
>
> [C1 C2 C3] = CSVIMPORT( fileName, 'columns', [1, 3, 4], ,'noHeader', true, ... ) 
>       This form returns the data from columns in output variables C1, C2 and C3 respectively, the 
>       columns parameter must contain the column indices when the 'noHeader' option is set to true.

So I used this:

```
[C2 C3] = csvimport('hugeCSV.csv','columns',2:3,'noHeader',true)
```

Using a smaller test csv file, that printed out something like this:

```
    C2 =

  439105
  439105
  439105
  439105
 1836139
 1464748
 1464748

  C3 = 

'1053224'
'1696241'
'580064'
'1464748'
'external'
'439105'
'1053224'
```

which is what I want. However, when I do it with the actual file of 948739 lines, I just get a list of numbers, something that looks like this:

```
  439105
  439105
  439105
  439105
 1836139
 1464748
 1464748
 1464748
 1464748
  580064
  580064
  580064
  580064
 1053224
```

And just goes on for quite a while...

So am I doing something wrong when calling CSVIMPORT? I just can't figure it out... Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: What is wrong with the output?

Comment: @Daniel I need it to print out like: `C1 = 1231 234235 345 123213 C2 = 542 6546 65464 354` With the huge csv file, all it returns is a list of numbers.

Comment: Check if the file is correctly formed. I mean, that all columns are respected in every row. If you have the chance try importing it in ms access for example, you will know if it's correct.

Comment: @eventHandler what do you mean that all the columns are respected in every row? Do you mean that there is data for every column?

Comment: matlab sucks for this kind of data. use learn R or perl. perl can chew through Gb of csv no problems.

Comment: @GAlexander Hmm... thanks for the info! I'll keep that in mind. The problem is that I have zero experience in either R or perl, and don't have time to learn them to fix this issue... I might see if I can split the csv file into parts and combine them all later

Comment: @ocean800 what i mean is you should check if every line has the exact same number of columns. No extra columns or blank columns. But i guess matlab would do this by default and create the necessary columns with zero values.

Comment: @GAlexander i don't think matlab sucks for this kind of data. It all depends on what you want to do with the data. filters, graphics, ....

Comment: @eventHandler Yeah, I know for a fact that the lines are correct.

Comment: what do you get if you print columns separetly. ommit output from your line using a semicolon, and then print `C2` for example. also print `length(C2)` and `length(C3)`. or instead print the first elements of each column `C2(1:100)` and `C3(1:100)`

Comment: @eventHandler omg thank you!! that worked... when I did length(C2) and length(C3) I got 948739 which is what I want. And both C2(1:100) and C3(1:00) work properly. The problem I think for me is that the console window won't display the whole column matrix because its too big. Do you know if there is any way of fixing that?

Comment: maybe the console can't handle such a large matrix and it kind of crashes. Maybe you ran out of memory. I don't know of a solution, but i'm pretty sure you don't need to display all the data, so i suggest to display only the necessary on the console.